# Ocaml characters

Tags: character-encoding, char, ocaml

In ruby I can do the following:

```
printf("%c ", 0x6A) # ┘
printf("%c ", 0x6B) # ┐
printf("%c ", 0x6C) # ┌
printf("%c ", 0x6D) # └
printf("%c ", 0x6E) # ┼ 
printf("%c ", 0x71) # ─
printf("%c ", 0x74) # ├
printf("%c ", 0x75) # ┤
printf("%c ", 0x76) # ┴
```

How do I print those chars with ocaml?

In Utop I get:

```
utop # let x = '0x6A';;
Error: Syntax error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally,

```
open Printf
printf "%c " '\x6A'
```

You can also use `char_of_int` function to convert integer codes into characters using ASCII encoding:

```
printf "%c" (char_of_int 0x6a)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also `Char.chr`

```
# Printf.printf "%c\n" (Char.chr 0x6A);;
j
- : unit = ()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to define x as a char type :

```
   # let x=char_of_int 0x6A;;
    val x : char = 'j'
    # Printf.printf "%c" x;;
    j- : unit = ()
```